# Boost asio & ssl & error code

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Considering this code:

```
const std::size_t rawBufferSize = 1024;
char rawBuffer[rawBufferSize] = { 0 };
boost::asio::ssl::stream< boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket >* sslStream;

... // initializing stuff

boost::system::error_code ec;
auto buffer = boost::asio::buffer(rawBuffer, rawBufferSize);

for(; ; )
{
   int readBytes = sslStream->read_some(buffer, ec); // I know that read_some return std::size_t (unsigned int)...

   // here, readBytes equals -1

   if (ec)
       break;

   ... (1)
}
```

How is it possible that "readBytes" equals -1 and the line "(1)" is reached.

Any clue of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's in your error_code variable when readBytes = -1?

Comment: @TonyTheLion If the line "(1)" is reached, I suppose "ec variable" was equal to zero.

Comment: read_some returns 0 [on error](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/read_some/overload2.html) not -1. Can you post a [short, self contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/) exhibiting the problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, your `error_code` variable is not a pointer, so the following if statement

```
if (ec)
   break;
```

does NOT check correctly if an error_code actually exists.

You need to do this to check as to whether an error_code exists:

```
if (ec.value() != 0) break;
```

Now, when an error has occurred, it will `break` correctly.

The value of the error_code, can be any of [these](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/system/doc/reference.html#Header-error_code) error conditions, inside the `enum`.

Comment: Are you suggesting the example code does not compile? The boolean conversion of an error_code is well described and used in many of the examples, including the [ssl client](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/ssl/client.cpp).

Answer (score 1):

In `error_code.hpp` you can find this definition:

```
class error_code
{
    ...

    typedef void (*unspecified_bool_type)();
    static void unspecified_bool_true() {}

    operator unspecified_bool_type() const  // true if error
    { 
      return m_val == 0 ? 0 : unspecified_bool_true;
    }

    bool operator!() const  // true if no error
    {
      return m_val == 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

If you use something like this:

```
if (!ec) {
    // no error
}
```

you get correct behavior, I hope it's clear. When you call this:

```
if (ec) {
    // error
}
```

you in fact call `operator unspecified_bool_type()`, because it returns a pointer (to function) and that can be converted to bool. If there is an error, it returns pointer to `unspecified_bool_true` which is not null. Therefore it works correctly and it won't solve the problem.